# Why can't I assign `push` function to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Here's my first example which works as expected:

```js
const testObj = {
   func: (str)=> { console.log(str) }
}

const testVar = testObj.func;

testVar("Working"); //logs "Working"
```

However if I try the same thing with a push function, it is undefined.

```js
const array = [];
const testVar = array.push;

console.log(testVar); // function push() { [native code]}

testVar("Should Be added"); // TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'testVar("Should Be added")')
```

Why is this?

Comment: because the context is lost. `testVar.call(array, "should be added")`

Comment: @KevinB Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` needs to know what `this` will be when you call it so it know what it's pushing into — normally this will be the array you called it on. If you separate the function from the array you lose that binding because `this` is set by the way you call a function. You can explicitly put it back together using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```js
const array = [];
const testVar = array.push;

testVar.call(array, "Should Be added"); 
console.log(array)
```

or [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
const array = [];
const testVar = array.push.bind(array);

testVar("some value")
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Is there any way to know if the function requires `this` context without testing it? `push` has `[native code]` so maybe not.

Comment: @JBis More or less any method you call on an object that depends on that object's state will need to access `this` because that's how it refers to itself in the method.

Answer (score 1):

when you make this `var push = [].push`; 
you make reference to utility function push from array type which use `this` inside it so when you make this `push('data')` 
it will give you `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` because `this` inside it now is `null|undefined`
so if you want to make this work you have to bring back the context like using `call` , 'apply' or `bind`

```js
/* call example */
var a = []
var push = a.push;
push.call(a, 'first elm')

/* apply example */
var a = [];
var push = a.push;
push.apply(a, ['first elm']);

/* bind example */
// Note: Bind doesn't execute the function but 
// it returns a new function with new context on it
var a = [];
var push = a.push;
var aBindPush = push.bind(a);
push('first elm');
```